# I can't insert values into the database using the .get() function

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter

I'm creating a table in a databse and I need to insert the values put into the entry to the database. I'm trying all kinds of stuff since a week. I'm a beginner. Could someone find the error?

I have tried all kinds of stuff using a variable and inserting the values directly using .get() and also using a ? placeholder.

```
from tkinter import*
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
cu = conn.cursor()
cu.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student(
             ID PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
             DATE TEXT NOT NULL,
             ADDRESS TEXT NOT NULL,
             MOBILE NUMBER REAL NOT NULL,
             NAME TEXT NOT NULL,
             QUALIFICATION TEXT NOT NULL,
             EMAIL TEXT NOT NULL,
             GENDER TEXT NOT NULL
             )""")
conn.commit()
print("Student Table successfully created ")
cu.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee(
             ID PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
             DATE TEXT NOT NULL,
             ADDRESS TEXT NOT NULL,
             MOBILE NUMBER REAL NOT NULL,
             NAME TEXT NOT NULL,
             QUALIFICATION TEXT NOT NULL,
             EMAIL TEXT NOT NULL,
             GENDER TEXT NOT NULL
             )""")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
print("Employee Table successfully created ")


def stud_win():
    studwin=Toplevel(root)
    studwin.title('Student registration')
    studwin.resizable(0,0)
    a = Label(studwin ,text = "ID" ).grid(row = 0,column = 0)
    b = Label(studwin ,text = "Date").grid(row = 1,column = 0)
    c = Label(studwin ,text = "Address").grid(row = 2,column = 0)
    d = Label(studwin ,text = "Mobile Number").grid(row = 3,column = 0)
    e = Label(studwin, text = "Name").grid(row=0, column=2)
    f = Label(studwin, text = "Qualification").grid(row=1, column=2)
    g = Label(studwin ,text = "Email").grid(row = 2,column = 2)
    h = Label(studwin, text = "Gender").grid(row = 3, column= 2)
    ID=IntVar
    a1 = Entry(studwin, textvariable=ID).grid(row = 0,column = 1)
    Date = StringVar
    b1 = Entry(studwin, textvariable=Date).grid(row = 1,column = 1)
    Address = StringVar
    c1 = Entry(studwin,textvariable=Address).grid(row = 2,column = 1)
    Number = StringVar
    d1 = Entry(studwin,textvariable=Number).grid(row = 3,column = 1)
    Name = StringVar
    e1 = Entry(studwin,textvariable=Name).grid(row = 0,column = 3)
    Qualification = StringVar
    f1 = Entry(studwin,textvariable=Qualification).grid(row = 1,column = 3)
    Email = StringVar
    g1 = Entry(studwin,textvariable=Email).grid(row = 2,column = 3)
    gender = StringVar()
    R1 = Radiobutton(studwin, text="Male", value="male", var=gender)
    R2 = Radiobutton(studwin, text="Female", value="female", var=gender)
    R1.grid(row = 3,column = 3)
    R2.grid(row = 3,column = 4)


    def btn_click1():
        ID = ID.get()
        Date =  Date.get()
        Address = Address.get()
        Number = Number.get()
        Name = Name.get()
        Qualification= Qualification.get()
        Email = Email.get()
        gender = gender.get()
        conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
        cu=conn.cursor()
        cu.execute('INSERT INTO student (ID,Date,Address,Number,Name,Qualification,Email,gender) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
                       (ID, Date, Address, Number, Name,Qualification,Email,gender,))
        conn.commit()
    i = Button(studwin, text="submit", command=btn_click1).grid(row=4, columnspan=4)
    studwin.mainloop()

root=Tk()
root.title("Registration form")
root.resizable(0,0)
menubar=Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Student", command=stud_win)
filemenu.add_command(label="Employee")
menubar.add_cascade(label="Register", menu=filemenu)
form_menu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
form_menu.add_command(label="Enrollment form")
menubar.add_cascade(label="Transaction", menu=form_menu)
exitmenu=Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
exitmenu.add_command(label="Exit App", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Exit", menu=exitmenu)    
root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

**Error**

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "F:\Python3\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1705, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)
>     File "F:/Python Projects/Registration form.py", line 71, in btn_click1
>       ID = ID.get()
>   UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ID' referenced before assignment

Comment: do you get error ? always put full error message (full Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you forgot `()` in many `StringVar()`

Comment: when you try to assing `ID = ...` then Python try to create local variable but later it sees `ID.get()` so it try to get value from local variable which doesn't exist yet. You would have to `global ID` inside function and it will use external `ID` instead of creating local one. But it will create another problem - it will assign value from `IntVar.get()` to `ID` so it will convert `IntVar` to normal `int` and next time it will try to use `get()` with normal `int`, not with `IntVar`. Better use different names or use `ID.get()` directly in execute(...)` without using `ID = ...`

Comment: using `a = Label(...).grid(...)` assigns `None` to `a`, not instance of `Label`,  because `grid()` returns `None` - if you need `a` to use it later then you have to do it in two steps: a = Label()` and `a.grid()`. If you don't use `a` later then you can skip it and use onlu `Label(...).grid(...)`. The same problem is with other `var = Widgets(...).grid(...)`

Comment: You've posted way too much code. Please try to reduce this down to a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ID = ID.get()` will not work because `ID` is a local variable that was defined in `stud_win()`, which means that you cannot access it from outside. You are trying to access it from `btn_click1()`, which triggers the exception.

In order to fix this, you have to make it a global variable. Same thing applies to all variables defined in `btn_click1()`

Comment: A global variable is a variable that can be accessed anywhere from the python file. So declare them in the top of the file not inside functions.